# ActiveRecord NoDatabaseError when attempting to connect to AWS MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, activerecord

We previously had a successful connection from Rails to an AWS MySQL instance through ActiveRecord, but as of our latest push to Heroku, that connection was severed. We don't understand why, as we have all traffic enabled on the AWS RDS settings, and the credentials in our database.yml config file have not changed. The only big thing that changed in the push to Heroku was adding the dovenv gem and passing control over environment variables to that gem.

When booting up our rails server in any of our three environments (dev, test, production), we receive a NoDatabaseError from ActiveRecord:

`ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError - Unknown database '<database_name>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'`

We *can* successfully connect to the database through MySQL CLI.

**database.yml:**

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: "<username>"
  password: "<password>"
  host: <database_name>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: <port>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test

production:
  <<: *default
```

**Relevant local dependencies:**

```
activerecord (5.1.4)
mysql2 (0.4.10)
rails (5.1.4)
```

**AWS security groups:**

```
default (<group_id>)    CIDR/IP - Inbound   0.0.0.0/0
default (<group_id>)    CIDR/IP - Outbound  0.0.0.0/0
Publicly accessible: Yes
```

**What we have tried:**

- Restarting MySQL server: `$ brew services list` `$ brew services restart mysql`
- Viewing MySQL logs on AWS, which reveals the error: `[Warning] IP address '<ip_address>' could not be resolved: Name or service not known`
- Testing in production, which when attempting to connect to the database, gives the error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: No database selected`
- Running `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development`, which gives the error:
  `` Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`<possibly_private_id>`.`us-east-1`.`rds`.`amazonaws`.`com` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8`' at line 1 ``
- Uninstalling mysql, /usr/local/var/mysql, and reinstalling mysql (through brew)
- Checking ENV variables, of which there are none that relate to MySQL.
- Confirmed that my mysql server is running by running `mysql.server status`

I have a theory that when installing the gem dotenv-rails, we may have lost some MySQL credentials that granted access to the server from our project's local directory... Again, we still can connect to the server through MySQL CLI so we know everything on AWS is fine and healthy. I also can't seem to log in to mysql as my local username, *or* root. Currently trying to figure that issue out.

Comment: It's literally looking for `'<database_name>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'` -> where was it getting `database_name` from previously? I notice that dev/test environments say `database: test` whereas prod doesn't define one... is that relevant? Is there a relevant environment variable that has not been added to `.env` ? heroku tends to have magic, dynamically-created ENV vars - it might be one of those...

Answer (score 0):

Solved - turns out it was related to the modifications I made in my environment variable setup. [In this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference) of the Rails Guides, it notes that specifically declaring "DATABASE_URL" as an environment variable *will* automatically set or override the `database` variable declared in your config/database.yml file.

In my case, the `host` variable (set in config/database.yml) was correctly set to `MY_DATABASE_NAME.amazon.aws`, but `DATABASE_URL` variable in my environment was silently setting the config file's `database` variable to the same `MY_DATABASE_NAME.amazon.aws`.

I do not have a database called 'MY_DATABASE_NAME.amazon.aws', which is why it was freaking out. Hope this helps someone else!